# Laurent expansion on border of annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

$$ f(z)= \frac{1}{(z-2)(z^2+i)} $$

I want to find the laurent expansion of this function at z=2 in the region

$$ 1 < |z| < 2 $$

if someone could help me with this not just telling me what to do but help me visualizing what this means.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The region you mentionne doesn't contain $2$.

Comment: This is the exactly how it was written in my exam by the professor, i doubt he got it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, this is nonsensical, since $2$ is not in the region $1<|z|<2,$ so we won't be able to help you visualize what it means. Probably what happened is that your professor copied and pasted from another problem, but didn't quite finish editing out the parts that weren't supposed to be there.

The best I can do for you, then, is speculate about what your professor may have intended to say, and see what sense the alternatives might make. Off the top of my head, the following could be what was intended:

1. Find the laurent expansion in the region $1<|z|<2.$
2. Find the laurent expansions at $z=2$ and in the region $1<|z|<2.$
3. Find the laurent expansion at $z=2.$
4. Find the laurent expansions at $z=2.$
5. Find the laurent expansion at $z=2$ in the region $1<|z-2|<2.$

Of course, it could be that something wildly different was intended, but those are the only obvious alternatives I can see.

I suspect that options 2-4 are incorrect (and know that option 5 is incorrect), for several reasons. For one, we typically specify regions for laurent expansions, unless the function is entire, which is not the case, here. Thus, asking for a laurent expansion at a point (a *singular* point, no less) is nonsensical. It could be that "at $z=2$" should be interpreted as "centered at $z=2,$" but even then, option 3 is nonsensical, as there are three annuli about $z=2$ on which a laurent series for $f(z)$ can be obtained, and it is not specified which of the three to use. Also, option 5 is impossible even under that interpretation, because the annulus $1<|z-2|<2$ contains the pole $z=-\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}.$ Thus, we're left with options 1, 2, and 4.

If we want to fully cover our options, we should assume that option 2 is what was meant, but that means finding four different laurent expansions, so in a testing situation, that would perhaps be inadvisable. However, it only differs from the posted problem by the single short word "and," so it could well be what was intended. It seems unlikely that option 4 was intended, because that would mean that the professor would have to misspell a word and fail to notice a fairly long phrase that wasn't supposed to be there, especially if "$1<|z|<2$" was typeset in the center, as it is in your post. It would be relatively easy to miss the short phrase "at $z=2,$" though, so I could easily see it being option 1.

The best advice I can give, if you encounter such a situation again, is to get up, take the exam copy to your professor, and ask for clarification. Everyone makes mistakes, and hopefully, your professor isn't the sort who won't admit to them.

If your professor is unwilling to provide such clarification, or if you are for some reason unwilling or unable to ask for it, there are really only two ways to go that I can see. You could assume that option 2 was meant, which would cover all the obvious options. Alternatively, you could (and in your place, I would) assume that option 1 was meant, then move on to the rest of the exam, and return to cover the other expansions if you have time to spare after completing the rest.

Comment: Isn't it possilbe though that the region is the intersection of $$ 1<|z|<2 $$ and $$ |z-2|< \sqrt{5} $$ where $$ \sqrt{5} $$ is the distance from the closest singularity. Isn't it possible to expand the series in this region?

Comment: The closest singularity to $z=2$ (aside from itself) is $z=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i,$ so the distance between them comes out to $\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{2}}.$ We can certainly expand it in the intersection of $|z-2|<\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{2}}$ and $1<|z|<2,$ but we could just as easily do so in the intersection of $|z-2|>\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{2}}$ and $1<|z|<2,$ and I see no reason to suspect that one of these is more likely to be the intended region than the other.

Comment: sry about the wrong math i brainlagged a bit and computed the wrong distance thanks for correcting me.Anyways, why would you assume that this couldn't be the desired region in this problem?

Comment: It's not that it couldn't be, it's just that I see no evidence that it should be. As I said in my answer, the five options that occurred to me are by no means the only ones that could've been intended, just the most obvious ones, based only on the text.

Comment: Couldn't it be that its $$ \sum a_n (z-2)^n $$ for the intersection $$|z-2|<\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{2}}  $$ and $$1<|z|<2 $$ and $$ \sum b_n (z-2)^{-n} $$ for the intersection $$|z-2|>\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{2}}  $$ and $$1<|z|<2 $$. If so is it correct to just compute the series and say that the regions are these intersections? Is there a way to write these intersections as one inequality?

Comment: It certainly could be! We can't reduce the intersections to a single inequality, but we can certainly express them as a single set, such as $$\left\{z\in\Bbb C:1<|z|<2\textrm{ and }|z-2|<\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{2}}\right\}.$$

Comment: See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%3C%7Cz%7C%3C2+and+%7Cz-2%7C%3Csqrt(5-2*sqrt(2))) for some other ways the region could be described.

Comment: I don't know what else to assume for this problem so after thinking about it all day this is the only thing i can come up with. Thanks for helping my friend!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: By the way, if you find an answer helpful, you can give it an upvote. If an answer completely (or at least sufficiently) addresses a question, you can also "accept" it by clicking the check mark. This garners reputation for you and the answerer, and lets other users know that the question has already been answered to the asker's satisfaction. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks for informing me i will do it!